# SQLDF failing on PostgreSQL Query From R

Tags: r, database, postgresql, odbc

PostgreSQL version: 11

R Version: 3.5.2

OS: Windows 10

Driver: PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)

```
library(RODBC)
library(sqldf)
conn = odbcConnect("DVDRental") #works
odbcDataSources() #works
sqlTables(conn) #works
customers = sqldf(connection = conn, "select * FROM customer") #fails
```

Error message: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’

Is there a newer way to connect R to Postgres? Googling uncovers a hodgepodge of code none of which seems to work.

If you want to try and run this, you can download the sample database I'm using here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/

I'm using a DSN called DVDRental.

Comment: Instead of searching the net suggest you read the documentation. There is nothing in the documentation that suggests that what you have done would work.

Comment: The documentation for what? For R, For RODBC? For sqldf? This code worked fine in 2015. I have no idea what changed but something did.

Comment: I was referring to `sqldf` since that is what you are using to run the sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RPostgreSQL` library to obtain the connection, using options:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

options(sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user ="postgres", 
    sqldf.RPostgreSQL.password ="password",
    sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname ="test",
    sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host ="localhost", 
    sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port =5432)

customers = sqldf("SELECT * FROM customer")
```

Comment: That fails too with the exact same error. Tried with and without. The version I posted was just what was sitting there after several hours of trying to figure out what should be a very basic task.

Comment: Question updated with no quotes around the connection object.